# linking members and channel entries

Tags: channel-entries, members

Is there a way within core EE or a third party add-on that can link members and channels?

Am building functionality where a member can upload personal files that will be stored as channel entries. The files will be accessed from the member home area by another member type.

Any help appreciated on how to tackle!

Comment: may be just create a channel for files, give members right to post into this channel with channel:forms and then sorted out by author_id?

Answer (score 2):

[Zoo visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/) and [Profile:Edit](http://mightybigrobot.com/products/detail/profile-edit) are two third-party modules which allow you to store members in channel entries; relationships to other channel content then become as simple as a relationship field in the user channel. (this of course also means that you can leverage things like categories and status for members).

IF you didn't want to go down the route of third party stuff, as long as the logged-in member was uploading their own file, you could access their stuff only within their profile by using the [author_id="CURRENT_USER"](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#author-id) parameter of the channel:entries tag pair.